# switching between databases based on session info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a set of 10 or so views that are identical across three databases. These views contain the databases' users, objects and so on. I'd like to be able to change the database connection based on the users session. In other words, the user logs in, selects which of the three databases they want to work with, and the models for the views use the appropriate connection.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how best to code for this. With multiple users using the app at the same time I believe I need to keep a pool of three connections alive (one for each database) in my models. I'm pretty sure I have that, what I can't figure out though is how I can force a model to use a specific connection before **every** find and how to pass it that info from the session.

Any thoughts on this approach as a whole? Got something better?

Comment: Have you considered instead running three instances, each configured for one of your three databases, then selectively redirecting to whichever of the 3 the user wishes to be working with (e.g. via subdomains)?

Comment: I have, the only issue comes with storing changes. I didn't mention it above, but users will be able to request changes to the relations. The three app solution breaks down when I'll inevitably hear "I requested these changes in database A, why do I have to request them again for database B?"

Comment: You might get something out of reading this eBook by [Ryan Bigg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15245/ryan-bigg):  https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails-2 @ryanbigg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gem was the silver bullet: https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus

I stored the database in the session and just use the `using` method before each of my searches.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some mileage out of using [`Thread.current`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html#method-c-current) and the overriding the [`connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-connection) method in your models.

You can set the target database in `Thread.current` when the user has it in their session:

```
before_filter :set_target_db

def set_target_db
  Thread.current[:target_database] = session[:the_db_they_chose]
end
```

Then in your models:

```
def self.connection
  case Thread.current[:target_database]
    when :first_db
      # Return connection from first pool
    when :second_db
      # Return connection from second pool
  end
end
```

Obviously you can share that code with all the models that store their data in the 3 databases you want to switch between.

I'm not sure I'd entirely advocate that approach though. It does sound a bit like you've got three separate applications that share common users and it might be better to approach it from that angle. Hard to say without knowing how much of the app depends on these three identical databases and how much is contained alongside the users.